# Can validation be applied to the whole table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have a models: `Stage` and `Task`(relationship one to many). Can I create column`status` (in model Stage) only for those stages that do not have tasks? can this be done using validation and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have columns that exist only conditional to a relation, but you can determine whether or not they contain values based on the presence of related records.

```
class Stage

  has_many :tasks

  validate :optional_status_correct

  def optional_status_correct
    if tasks.present? && status.present?
      errors.add(:status, 'cannot have status if tasks present')
    elsif tasks.blank? && status.blank?
      errors.add(:status, 'must have status')
    end
  end

end
```